# G1 Full GC events happens too often due to Allocation Failure

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I have a backend service using G1 GC, which has started full gc so frequently after running about 2 days.

the original application gc params（eliminating gc log params for better readability ）:

```
-Xms32g -Xmx32g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:G1ReservePercent=15 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20
```

GC params in gc log:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_202-b08), built on Jan 22 2019 13:35:07 by "jenkins" with gcc 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Memory: 4k page, physical 263567564k(2925568k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: 
-XX:CICompilerCount=15 -XX:ConcGCThreads=6 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16777216 (16MB)
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=15 -XX:InitialHeapSize=34359738368(32GB) 
-XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:MaxHeapSize=34359738368 
-XX:MaxNewSize=20602421248 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=16777216 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC
```

and the full gc logs:

```
2023-10-06T08:31:44.068+0800: 659309.919: 
[Full GC (Allocation Failure)  23G->21G(32G), 19.5437974 secs] [Eden: 16.0M(6000.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 544.0M->0.0B 
Heap: 23.8G(32.0G)->21.3G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90182K->90182K(94208K)] 
[Times: user=27.33 sys=1.05, real=19.54 secs] 

2023-10-06T09:15:45.544+0800: 661951.395: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  31G->20G(32G), 14.5219354 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(6544.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.7G(32.0G)->20.4G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90216K->90216K(94208K)]
 [Times: user=19.32 sys=1.00, real=14.52 secs] 

2023-10-06T09:47:37.129+0800: 663862.980: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  31G->20G(32G), 15.0624531 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(6544.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.7G(32.0G)->20.5G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90217K->90199K(94208K)]
 [Times: user=18.48 sys=2.25, real=15.06 secs] 

2023-10-06T10:11:54.450+0800: 665320.301: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  31G->20G(32G), 14.5384049 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(6544.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.7G(32.0G)->20.7G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90217K->90202K(94208K)]
 [Times: user=18.65 sys=1.60, real=14.54 secs] 

2023-10-06T10:36:51.857+0800: 666817.708: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  31G->20G(32G), 14.1996159 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(6544.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.7G(32.0G)->20.7G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90213K->90205K(94208K)]
 [Times: user=18.68 sys=1.30, real=14.20 secs] 

2023-10-06T11:00:10.119+0800: 668215.970: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  31G->20G(32G), 14.1973267 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(6544.0M)->0.0B(6544.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.7G(32.0G)->20.8G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 90218K->90211K(94208K)]
 [Times: user=19.31 sys=0.77, real=14.20 secs]
```

the gc param G1ReservePercent=15 means that G1 will ensure at least 15% free space as pointed in [gceasy](https://gceasy.io/gc-recommendations/important-g1-gc-arguments.jsp#:%7E:text=The%20default%20value%20is%20200%20milliseconds.&text=Sets%20the%20size%20of%20a,range%20from%201MB%20to%2032MB.)

> Sets the percentage of reserve memory to keep free. The default is 10 percent. G1 Garbage collectors will try to keep 10% of the heap to be free always.

Which means g1 will start a (old? mixed?) gc to match the G1ReservePercent constraint when heap grows up to about 27G (85% of 32G).

But the full gc log `31.7G(32.0G)->20.8G(32.0G)` shows that the heap has exhausted, it's too late to start a non full gc.

So what's wrong with the full gc problem and why G1ReservePercent param doesn't work.

Comment: The question probably should be what's wrong with your application.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to dictate the New Space size? The first thing I’d do, is to start with the minimal set of options and let the JVM do its job and only add options when I’m confident that I know better than the JVM what’s good in this specific scenario and why. Especially when there’s a large amount of Old Space to reclaim on every GC, forcing a small New Space might have been the wrong thing…

Comment: Adding to @Holger, maybe not setting `ms == mx`since that will turn off heap ergonomics.

Comment: thanks to @Holger  and Erik , I will try to just use the default args and see what will happen. Reply later...